# Effect of Find Command in Hard Drive

Tags: linux, macos

I m using the find command to search for modified files in a folder every minute. The folder contains a little over a thousand files. Since i m running the find command every minute , will it affect my Hard Drive , will there be any other effects on my System Resources ..?

Comment: What do you mean by "affect"? reduce it's lifetime? Are you experiencing any real performance problems?

Comment: i don't see any problems yet, i'm testing the script now, but before i get it to production, i need to know there any effect on Hard drive, such as large reads, reducing lifetime, slowing down the disk.etc

Comment: It may be better to use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) -- [example with Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316178/watching-multiple-files-with-inotify-in-perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desktop computer systems run background processes like desktop search indexers that access far more than the metadata of 1000 files per minute. In that regard, your program does not produce a lot of additional load on the system. It's also possible that some cache or other optimization will reduce load on the actual disk. Unless you're actually experiencing performance issues, I wouldn't worry about it.

However, if you're using your find results to `-exec` something, e.g. `fgrep`, that's different and depends on *how* you're using the results of your search.